# Отрисовка Shape с применением Shape маски

Tags: android, canvas, mask, shape

Имеются две фигуры, `shape` и `maskShape` класса `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape`

Как отрисовать на `android.graphics.Canvas` фигуру с использованием второй фигуры как маску без дополнительных буферных битмапов?

Comment: что вы понимаете под буфером в данном случае? вам надо загрузить как минимум 2 Bitmap а потом их объединять в одном из них. Paint setXfermode в помощь.

Comment: Под буферным битмапом имею ввиду битмап, на котором рисуется "shape", a потом с помощью BitmapShader на Canvas рисуется "maskShape" методом drawCircle или drawRect в зависимости от типа "maskShape".

Comment: Я пытаюсь исключить дополнительное выделение памяти

Comment: Дополнительное выделение памяти можно сократить если Bitmap маски создавать с флагом типа ALPHA - в 3 раза меньше